# How to retrieve data from Custom Post Types wordpress using php

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-shortcode, acfpro

I'm trying to show the data inserted into custom post types in a table and I'm having trouble showing values in front end underneath each column i.e (Duration, Incall, Outcall)

[image]

[image]

```
                <table class="rates-table">
                <?php $get_rates_list = get_field('rates_optional');
                        if(get_rates_list){
                            foreach($get_rates_list as $rate){?>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <td><h3 class="inside-model-single">Duration</h3></td>
                        <td><h3 class="inside-model-single">Incall</h3></td>
                        <td><h3 class="inside-model-single">Outcall</h3></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            
                            <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span class="rate_value"><?php echo $rate['incall_1_hour'];?></span></td>
                            <td><span class="rate_value"><?php echo $rate['outcall_1_hour'];?></span></td>
                          </tr>
                        <?php }
                        }?>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is displaying by its `Name` individually using [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) or [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/).

```
<table class="rates-table">
  <?php $incall_1_hour = get_field('incall_1_hour'); ?>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><h3 class="inside-model-single">Duration</h3></td>
      <td><h3 class="inside-model-single">Incall</h3></td>
      <td><h3 class="inside-model-single">Outcall</h3></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="rate_value"><?php echo $incall_1_hour; ?></span></td>
      <td><span class="rate_value"><?php the_field('outcall_1_hour'); ?></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Second way is using [get_fields()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/) to get an array of all field values for current or a specific post. Following is just a simple example as I don't know the full structure of your post. Make your changes accordingly.

```
<?php $get_rates_list = get_fields();

if ($get_rates_list) {
  foreach($get_rates_list as $rate) {
    ?><td><span class="rate_value"><?php echo $rate;?></span></td><?php
  }
} ?>
```

Comment: This works fine how can I change this to table?

`<?php $get_rates_list = get_field('rates');
       if(get_rates_list){
        foreach($get_rates_list as $rate){?>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
          <span class="rate_label"><?php echo $rate['rate_title'];?></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col">
          <span class="rate_value"><?php echo $rate['incall'];?></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col">
          <span class="rate_value"><?php echo $rate['outcall'];?></span>
         </div>
        </div>
       <?php }
       }?>`

Comment: does `echo $rate['rate_title']` display the required value?

Comment: Well I have created 2 different options in ACF one with the title and the other without title just the repeater so it shows the title which not not set but after someone add's a post item with title and it get's that title and display it. The above code comment code works fine just want to convert it to a formatted table instead of row and col's

Comment: ah, ok. If its repeater field then it should work fine. your `if (get_rates_list) {` is missing `$`. Here is an example for the table with foreach loop. again make your changes accordingly. https://gist.github.com/zohaib87/71ca0f36a84ad8f6548a4742af0e8225